# Modified Joomla Template now no main area links work in Chrome, but work fine in IE?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, joomla

After being out of the web development game for over a decade, I'm back and now rebuilding a school's site based on a Joomla template.  Now on Chrome even a basic HTML  tag won't bring up a link in the main template.  All mailto links disappear (literally anything with an email address disappears from the text of the site) as well-- and was giving some random "install javascript" message.

This is the site.  We had to do a bunch of CSS cutting and hacking to get the template to fit the visuals we needed.

http://www.novaschool.org/index.php/nova-home

If anyone has any ideas, I'm forever in your debt!!!  Most of the teachers use Chrome, so we're never going to get far.

Cheers,
sam (who started web programming in '94, but hasn't done much of anything hands-on since '98)

Answer (score 2):

There are a great many issues with this site. Critically, it *really* needs to be updated to a current,secure, version of Joomla.

The issues you are referring to though are because 1) your links are white in colour and the background is white, rendering them invisible and 2) the menu is set to be 90% of the width of the body and uses absolute positioning, making it impossible to interact with any element beneath it.

Honestly, if I were you I'd start with a fresh current installation of Joomla and copy your content across, it will be far less work than bringing this one up to scratch.

p.s. For future reference, there's a [Joomla specific Stack Exchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/).